# Getting error while running java program in jenkins on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

This is my java code:
pranit@pranit-master:~/java_labs$ cat First.java

```
public class First {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello");

}
}
```

This is the build job I am running in jenkins for a java program. Below is the job console output.

```
Started by user Anmol Bhoir
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /home/pranit/java_labs
[java_labs] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins5091110815182762939.sh
+ javac First.java
**First.java:2: error: error while writing First: /home/pranit/java_labs/First.class
public class First {
       ^
1 error**
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm getting above error while running the java program in jenkins on ubuntu OS.
But the same program if i execute on Ubuntu, I dont get any issues. It is running fine only.

Please help me with this issue. Cannot proceed further because of this.

I tried many solutions like giving classpath while running the java code using -cp option, but did not work.
eg.

## javac -cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin First.java

Comment: It is just a simple java class, I don't think you need `-cp`. With java 11 and upper, just use command `java First.java`

Comment: Ohh It worked. I was first compiling my program and then running the java code because that is what normally we do.. Now I removed the compilation step and it worked successfully. Thanks mate.

Comment: Glad it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.  
This is a permission issue. 
Solution: Go to your TARGET_JAVA_FILENAME.class properties and Go to permissions tab and set others access to Read and write. 
[image]

Now it should work